Why use quarkus resources instead of services and controllers?
Well, maybe this is a beginner's question, but I had trouble finding a clear explanation in the official documentation or other sources.
I'm a computer science student with just over a year and a half of programming experience. I'm more used to developing backend using spring boot, in which I usually use a structure of services and controllers, the services being responsible for the business logic and the controllers for the requests.
However, I've recently started to study Quarkus more. When looking at example code from the framework, I saw that instead of controllers, resources are used that join the controllers with the services. Basically, I don't understand why I should do it this way instead of separating things, maybe I'm too used to the way I did it before, but I'd like to understand a little better what the advantages of this choice are, if it's the best way (I know it depends a lot, but what factors influence this decision) and well, are there any risks in terms of the responsibilities of each layer when applying this way of developing?
Well, that's it, I'd really appreciate it if you could help me with that!
Well, in terms of what I've done, I'm just studying and I think this is more theoretical content. But here's a generic feature I've implemented, basically I did it this way to make basic crud operations easier. But one thing you might notice is that the resource has direct access to the entity, is this correct when thinking about encapsulation, security and the responsibility of the layers? How could I improve it?
package com.dotgrupo.generic.resource;

import com.dotgrupo.exception.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.dotgrupo.generic.entity.GenericEntity;
import com.dotgrupo.generic.utils.Updatable;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Consumes;
import jakarta.ws.rs.DELETE;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST;
import jakarta.ws.rs.PUT;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.PathParam;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.Operation;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.responses.APIResponse;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.responses.APIResponses;

import java.util.List;

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public abstract class GenericResource<T extends GenericEntity> {
    private final Class<T> entityClass;

    @Inject
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public GenericResource(final Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    @GET
    @Operation(summary = "Get all entities", description = "Returns a list of all entities.")
    @APIResponses(value = {
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "List of entities returned successfully."),
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal server error.")
    })
    public List<T> getAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName(), entityClass).getResultList();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Operation(summary = "Get an entity by ID", description = "Returns the entity corresponding to the provided ID.")
    @APIResponses(value = {
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Entity found."),
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Entity not found.")
    })
    public T get(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        T entity = entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Entity with id " + id + " does not exist.");
        }
        return entity;
    }

    @POST
    @Transactional
    @Operation(summary = "Create a new entity", description = "Creates a new entity.")
    @APIResponses(value = {
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "Entity created successfully."),
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Error in entity creation.")
    })
    public Response create(T entity) {
        entity.id = null;
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(entity).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Transactional
    @Operation(summary = "Update an existing entity", description = "Updates the entity corresponding to the provided ID.")
    @APIResponses(value = {
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Entity updated successfully."),
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Entity not found.")
    })
    public Response update(@PathParam("id") Long id, T entity) {
        T existingEntity = entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
        if (existingEntity == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Entity with id " + id + " does not exist.");
        }
        updateEntity(existingEntity, entity);
        entityManager.merge(existingEntity);
        return Response.ok(existingEntity).build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    @Transactional
    @Operation(summary = "Delete an entity", description = "Deletes the entity corresponding to the provided ID.")
    @APIResponses(value = {
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "204", description = "Entity deleted successfully."),
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Entity not found.")
    })
    public Response delete(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        T entity = entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Entity with id " + id + " does not exist.");
        }
        entityManager.remove(entity);
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }

    protected void updateEntity(T existingEntity, T newEntity) {
        Updatable.updateProperties(existingEntity, newEntity);
    }
}


I don't know if my implementation helps you understand my question, but I hope so!

Architecturally, JAX-RS resources are identical to Spring MVC controllers (not exactly in terms of features, although they are still pretty similar there too). Whether you should create a generic resource like this, or delegate to a service that does the data manipulation, is up to you I guess -- but it will most likely eventually turn out that you need a lot more business logic and most likely don't want to return entities directly, in which case you'll naturally resort to services anyway.

@Ladicek sounds like a proper answer (not a comment) to me :)

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
